# issue while running elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize modules

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize modules

Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /Users/NiveditaKumari/Downloads/elasticsearch-5.6.0/modules/.DS_Store/plugin-descriptor.properties: Not a directory

I am not able to run elasticsearch , I am facing above issue

Answer (score 1):

Check all files and folder in modules folder and remove `.DS_Store`
follow these steps

1. `cd modules`
2. `ls -a`
3. `rm .DS_Store`

You can take this image as reference:

[image]